# Is there a way to find the home screen directory?

Tags: java, android, path, homescreen, android-launcher

How can I get the path of a folder in the home screen?

My problem is that I can't think of away to get the path of a folder in the home screen. Let's say i have a folder with some applications in it that I see it on the home screen.I want to get the path of the folder.

Comment: describe your problem more details

Comment: My problem is that I can't think of away to get the path of a folder in the home screen. Let's say i have a folder with some applications in it that I see it on the home screen.I want to get the path of the folder.

Comment: Home screens do not have to offer any sort of "folder" concept. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of home screen implementations for Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the default Android Launcher (which can be replaced) you are making on major mistake:

You assume that Android home screen works like the Windows Desktop - which is wrong.

In Android the is no such think like a desktop folder, therefore the "home screen directory" does not exist.

The apps on the home screen are usually database entries managed by the launcher which is itself an app.